# Unable to get s3.Object ACL using AWS SDK in go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to list the objects of one bucket using the official [example](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/example/service/s3/listObjects/listObjects.go)

```
    err = svc.ListObjectsPages(&s3.ListObjectsInput{
        Bucket: &bucketName,
    }, func(p *s3.ListObjectsOutput, last bool) (shouldContinue bool) {
        fmt.Println("Page,", i)
        i++

        for _, obj := range p.Contents {
            fmt.Println("Object:", *obj.Key)
        }
        return true
    })
```

However I see that the `s3.Object` [type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#Object) does not have any ACL information associated with it.

How can I get the `s3.Object`'s ACL information?

Comment: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils/blob/master/aws/S3/S3Utils.go

Refer to this library in order to understand how to deal with `aws-sdk-go-v2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this example to learn how to get an Amazon S3 object's ACL information using the AWS SDK for Go V2.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/gov2/s3/GetObjectAcl